# Mac to-do list, sticks to desktop

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, to-do

Looking for a free to-do list app for Mac that allows you to quickly add/remove tasks and is permanently attached to the desktop. I have seen other apps like Anxiety but they have the window float above others. I need something that is stuck to the desktop while letting other windows go in front of it.

EDIT: I'm on 10.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions but I think I've found a solution. [Stick 'Em Up](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/23711) does exactly what I need. The note will stay on the desktop, behind other windows, and if I want to add something to the list, I just need to click and type.

Hopefully this is useful to someone else who is looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

This may apply to any widget including the "Travel To-Do List" suggested. Comes in handy in case you can't find a particular app, but have the widget.

If you have any widget from the dashboard that you would like to use on the desktop.

1. open 'Terminal'
2. type 'defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES'
3. restart dashboard

When this is done, hold onto a widget while in Dashboard and press F12. The widget then transfers to the regular desktop. To move it back, repeat from the desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the widget stays in front of all other windows. I need something that "sticks" to the desktop.

Comment: Haha, looks like that was overlooked by me. Anyways, other than what was already mentioned, Yahoo Widgets? Not home on the mac right now, so I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Travel To-Do List**](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/travel/traveltodolist.html) widget for the dashboard, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

[Check Off](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/checkoff/) is a to-do list that sits in your Mac's menu bar.

[image: Check Off main window]

Comment: it is now paid - I didn't even try it...